# How do I write a program in Go that opens a file in an editor and upon exiting, resumes the program?

Tags: go, process, fork, exec

I need to write a function in Go that opens a file in Vim or Nano and then upon exiting the editor, have the Go program resume.

Here's what I have:

```
func OpenEd(page string) error {
    pagePath := GetPath(page, DEBUG)
    ed := "/usr/bin/nano"
    cmd := exec.Command(ed, pagePath)
    err := cmd.Start()
    cmd.Wait()

    return err
}
```

It runs with no error but does nothing. I was thinking that I would have had to fork the main process to run the exec functionality properly like what is typical in C. But I looked into that and I don't think that's how it's handled in Go. But I'm not sure, Go is fairly new to me.

This code in C runs exactly how I want the Go code to run:

```
void openEd(void)
{
    int rc;

    char *args[] = {"test.txt", NULL};

    rc = fork();
    if (rc == 0) {
        execvp("nano", args);
    }
    wait(&rc);
}
```

How do I get this Go function to run like this C function?

Comment: @Zombo I tried that originally but it just hangs for a second then does nothing. Either way, I should have that in the question. I'll update it. Thanks.

Comment: The program ignores the error returned from cmd.Wait().   Simplify the code and get the error by replacing `err := cmd.Start(); cmd.Wait()` with `err := cmd.Run()`.   The error may point to the problem.

Comment: @Zombo Thanks, I tried it. it just says "exit status 1". It actually does seem to open nano, just not in the terminal. running `top` shows nano running as a process and while it's running, my Go program just hangs. Killing the nano process causes my Go program to finish which then returns the "exit status 1"